# Assign value from one dateframe to another in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames, df1 and df2 (see below). From df1 I want to write the value of `letter` into the relevant column in df2, such e.g. that the value `group.x` for `ID=1` is C and `group.y` is B (from df1). As I don't really know where to start looking for answers, some help in pointing me in the right direction for solving this would be greatly appreciated...

```
> no.pers <- 3
> df1 <- data.frame(
+   ID = rep(1:no.pers, each = 3),
+   letter = sample(LETTERS[1:3],
+                   no.pers*3,
+                   replace = TRUE),
+   group = rep(letters[seq(24,26)],
+                  no.pers,
+                  replace = TRUE)
+   )
> df1
  ID letter group
1  1      C     x
2  1      B     y
3  1      C     z
4  2      C     x
5  2      B     y
6  2      B     z
7  3      B     x
8  3      C     y
9  3      B     z
> df2 <- data.frame(ID = unique(df1$ID),
+                   setNames(
+                     replicate(length(unique(df1$group)),
+                               0,
+                               simplify = FALSE),
+                     paste0("group.",unique(df1$group)))
+                   )
> df2
  ID group.x group.y group.z
1  1       0       0       0
2  2       0       0       0
3  3       0       0       0
```

Comment: Can't you just work with `df1` while ignoring `df2` completely? something like `reshape2::dcast(df1, ID ~ group, value.var = "letter")`?

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks! If you want to make it into an answer, I can accept it as answered...

Comment: This was answered many times on SO, as this is a very common data manipulation procedure. See the dupe. It has many other possibilities too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Alright, I am deleting the answer if you are so particular about the dupe thing.  The fact is that the OP have enough time to google before posting a question.  If he/she doesn't do that, why should I google for a potential dupe.  It's just a waste of my time.

Comment: @akrun OP isn't familiar with R/R terminology enough to know how to Google such thing in the first place.

Comment: @DavidArenburg In my workplace, most of the sites are blocked.  Also, I dont think I should be doing the google for them.

Comment: @akrun you found a job? Congrats man!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, sort of.